# Problem in Deleting Model Entries having ForeignKey Constraint

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

```
class Client(models.Model):
   client_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class Cont(models.Model):
    contid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    Client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class ContractDailyIndent(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    cont = models.ForeignKey(Cont, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class VDLContract(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    contractindent = models.ForeignKey(ContractDailyIndent, 
on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**Getting error in this line**
 VDLContract.objects.filter(contractindent__cont__Client__in=clients).delete()

It's giving error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/puranjay/Documents/FeasOpt/new/fo_ftl_puranjay/mysite/empanelment/views.py", line 10432, in update_client_type
    delete_client_type(user, client_type_id)
  File "/home/puranjay/Documents/FeasOpt/new/fo_ftl_puranjay/mysite/empanelment/views.py", line 105, in delete_client_type
    delete_indent_models(user, clients)
  File "/home/puranjay/Documents/FeasOpt/new/fo_ftl_puranjay/mysite/empanelment/utility.py", line 962, in delete_indent_models
    raise e
  File "/home/puranjay/Documents/FeasOpt/new/fo_ftl_puranjay/mysite/empanelment/utility.py", line 941, in delete_indent_models
    VDLContract.objects.filter(contractindent__cont__Client__in=clients).delete()

File "/home/puranjay/Documents/FeasOpt/env/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 661, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)

File "/home/puranjay/Documents/FeasOpt/env/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 222, in collect
    field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: Is there something that *refers* to your `VDLCOntract` (so a `ForeignKey`, etc.)?

Comment: It looks that is gives an error on `vdl_market_object` by the way, not the above queryset `.delete()` call...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Have posted and updated my error. Please check now

Comment: it just looks like something is protecting the object from being deleted. Likely an `ForeignKey` that refers to the `VDLContract` model.

Comment: But I am trying to delete them in sequence and even it is not giving foreign key constraint.

Comment: the fact that it is a queryset does not matter. It looks like you used `on_delete=models.PROTECT` somewhere. `PROTECT` means it does not allow you to remove objects that are referred by that FK. The traceback seems to suggest that.

Comment: No @WillemVanOnsem, that's not the case here, django allows you to delete when there is no dependency with parent model, even if models.PROTECT is used.
which means if he has deleted all related appropriate entries with respect to parent model, it should let you delete, error is not because of any foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried implementing your problem on my localmachine.
Django causes this error because of foreign key constraint.This happens when your foreign key is dependent on other  models, in your case VDLContract may have dependency on other model which need to be deleted first.

Comment: Yes it had some dependency on some other models. Thanks For the help.

Comment: Happy to help you bro